# Image jumps when click on next or previous on bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am working on a site and integrated the bootstrap carousel. Everything is working well, except for a one thing that: When I click on next or previous icon, images will jump a little bit and I feel very annoying about it. I tried every solutions which I have searched and applied but it still didn't work.
Can anybody help me with this problem, the url as below:
https://test5.extensionesdepelobaratas.net/hair-blog/
You will see the first carousel which have number from 1 to 8.
Look forward to hearing solutions from everybody.

Thank you very much.

Comment: try removing `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` from the `.carousel-inner>.item.active` style

Comment: Hi. thank you very much for your suggestion. I tried but it still didn't work. It keeps the same, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a handful of elements with the class .item which are not properly being transitioned when it comes to it's attributes and the active class ones which are being applied thereafter.

If you add the following CSS to your .carousel-inner .item elements, all of the values will be transitioned properly.

```
.carousel-inner .item { transition: all 0.5s ease !important; }
```

Tested this with the existing website and there is no more 'jumpiness' when it comes to the elements sliding in. Instead, they grow rather than jump to the size which the carousel is setting them as.

Comment: hi. thank you very much. I see that it seems like the images doesn't change the height when click on next/previous. But the animation is very weird now and it still make its below element jumping. You can check the url to see: https://test5.extensionesdepelobaratas.net/hair-blog/